# How can I get metadata from pdf document using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Is there any way to get metadata from pdf document like author or title using pdf.js?

In this example : http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf

```
<div class="row">
<span data-l10n-id="document_properties_author">
    Autor:
</span>
<p id="authorField">
    -
</p>
```

And the authorField is empty. Is there any way to get this info?

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the code you use or something?

Comment: The PDF does not have the author field populated. Display a different document, e.g. http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=/deuxdrop/pdf-docs/conversation-protocol.pdf

Answer (score 13):

Using just the PDF.js library without a thirdparty viewer, you can get metadata like so, utilizing promises.

```
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
        pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;   
        pdfDoc.getMetadata().then(function(stuff) {
            console.log(stuff); // Metadata object here
        }).catch(function(err) {
           console.log('Error getting meta data');
           console.log(err);
        });

       // Render the first page or whatever here
       // More code . . . 
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error getting PDF from ' + url);
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I found this out after dumping the `pdfDoc` object to the console and looking through its functions and properties. I found the method in its prototype and decided to just give it a shot. Lo and behold it worked!

Comment: I presume that your phrase "utilizing promises" is a mistake which was introduced during spellchecking? :)

Comment: To 'view' the object contents you can: console.log(JSON.stringify(stuff,null,2))

Comment: Where does "PDFJS" come from, its all undefined when I try to use it.

Comment: @mondjunge I wrote this answer over 5 years ago, unfortunately, and don't do JavaScript work anymore. It's possible the library has since been updated. Maybe check out some of the newer example code here? https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

Comment: I included pdf.js from its github page and now it works. Guess the Firefox included pdf.js has some kind of protective layer?!

Answer (score 2):

You can get document basic metadata info from PDFViewerApplication.documentInfo object. For eg: to get Author use PDFViewerApplication.documentInfo.Author

Answer (score 0):

```
pdfDoc.getMetadata(url).then(function(stuff) {
    var metadata = stuff.info.Title;
    if (metadata) {
        $('#element-html').text(stuff.info.Title); // Print metadata to html
    }
console.log(stuff); // Print metadata to console
}).catch(function(err) {
     console.log('Error getting meta data');
     console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
await getDocument(url).promise.then(doc => doc.getMetadata())
```