# Read metadata from pdf using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am successfully implemented viewing pdf file.I want to Get meta data from PDF file and show specific page in my app.but, I cant able to find solution for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743491/how-can-i-get-metadata-from-pdf-document-using-pdf-js check the second answer

Comment: I have tried this solution.i cant able to implement at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get metadata from pdf document using pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743491/how-can-i-get-metadata-from-pdf-document-using-pdf-js)

Comment: They are not provided documents to implement this.i m tried this solution  to